# edit "Additional information" to an other name?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category

I would like to transform the "Additional information" to an other name like "feature". where file i will update or edit?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can find it in default theme at-

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

For custom theme the path will be something like -

```
app/design/frontend/default/customTheme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. That help me to resolve my problem with an other solution